# How is a parallete planche changed by bending the elbows?

Tags: calisthenics, gymnastics

Is the primary targeted musculature changed from the front deltoids? And is the overall targeted musculature changed? (From a normal one where the elbows are extended straight, the shoulders at 90deg and the body horizontally parallel to the floor to the elbows bent to nearly 90deg, the shoulders more or less in a neutral position, and the body in the same flat horizontal position parallel to the floor).

What else changes about this exercise when it is so modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They both use predominantly the shoulders and a bit of chest. The main difference between a planche and a 90° hold is that with planche using straight arms, the point of contact with the floor is further away from from shoulder creating a longer lever and thus making the planche considerably harder.

Comment: That's not the only difference. A bent arm planche puts a lot of stress on the triceps, while a planche with locked out arms puts more stress on the biceps.

Comment: @MJB why would that be? What are the mechanics of the shifting stress?

Comment: Btw do the rotator cuff muscles get recruited in this at all?

Comment: @Seekinganswers  because when you have (slightly) bent arms, you're pushing to keep your arms from bending further (which is done by the triceps). When you have full straight locked out arms, you keep tension on the biceps to not let them bend further passed the straight point.

Comment: @MJB - what you say is true but I didn't think it worth mentioning because the amount of work done by your bi's and tri's is pretty inconsequential compared to the stress on your shoulders and chest.

Comment: @Ethan I don't know if you can personally do a planche, but I can and I have to disagree that it's inconsequential compared to stress on the chest. Yes, shoulders are under a lot more stress than bi's and tri's. But the chest? A planche looks from a bystander point of view like it should be really hard for your chest, but in my experience after a planche training I hardly feel my chest, while my biceps definitely get sore the day after due to the stress of the static hold of plance training. This is just personal experience tho, so purely anecdotal evidence.

Comment: @MJB - No I can't really do a planche so I wouldn't know for myself, but I can do the 90° hold, and I've never really felt any considerable tricep involvement in that one.

Comment: @Ethan Okay, but even if you don't feel it you know how the arm works right? The triceps straightens the arm, while the biceps bends it. So if your arm is in at 90° static hold, you can understand how the triceps is working to make sure it doesn't bend any further, right?